# How to calculate response and callback time in the case of AJAX Call?I'm calculating this using a js file and a html file. index.html part

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

```js
 
<script >
$( document ).ready(function() {
 
  $("#acall").click(function() {
   startTime = new Date().getTime();
   localStorage.setItem('startTime', startTime);
  var ajaxTime= new Date().getTime();
  /* var dataLength = JSON.stringify(data).length; */
  $.ajax({ 
   
       type: 'GET', 
       url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',  
       /* url: 'http://192.168.0.101:9090/Lab/login?username=usre&password=usre',   */ 
    //  data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
      dataType: 'text',
      async : true,
     
      start_time: new Date().getTime(),
      success: function (data, msg) {
    //alert(data);
     //console.log('This request took '+(new Date().getTime() - this.start_time)+' ms');
    /* document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data; */
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = msg;
    var ajaxEnddd = new Date().getTime();
    /* console.log("Hello"); */
    
     document.getElementById("demorst").innerHTML ="Ajax Response Time: "+localStorage.getItem('rst')+" ms";
     document.getElementById("democbt").innerHTML ="Ajax Callback Time: "+(ajaxEnddd - localStorage.getItem('rs4date'))+" ms";
      }
  }) 
  /* var ajaxEnd = new Date().getTime();
  document.getElementById("demom").innerHTML = ajaxEnd - ajaxTime; */
  
 });
  
 });
</script>
   // And the js file is
 XHR.prototype.send = function(data) {
       
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      
     var self = this;
        var start;
        var oldOnReadyStateChange;
        var url = this._url;
        
        if (self.readyState == 1){
         
            var rs1date = new Date().getTime();
             localStorage.setItem('rs1date', rs1date);
          } 
        
        function onReadyStateChange() { 
    if(self.readyState == 4 && self.status == 200) {
             
             
             var rs4date = new Date().getTime();
            
             localStorage.setItem('rs4date', rs4date);
             var rst = (localStorage.getItem('rs4date')-localStorage.getItem('rs1date'));
             localStorage.setItem('rst',rst);
  
            }
//From html file when I'm doing ajax call it calling js file too, and I
```

And the js file is

```js
I'm calculating this using a js file and a html file.
index.html part
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
 
  $("#acall").click(function() {
   startTime = new Date().getTime();
   localStorage.setItem('startTime', startTime);
  var ajaxTime= new Date().getTime();
  /* var dataLength = JSON.stringify(data).length; */
  $.ajax({ 
   
       type: 'GET', 
       url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',  
       /* url: 'http://192.168.0.101:9090/Lab/login?username=usre&password=usre',   */ 
    //  data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
      dataType: 'text',
      async : true,
     
      start_time: new Date().getTime(),
      success: function (data, msg) {
    //alert(data);
     //console.log('This request took '+(new Date().getTime() - this.start_time)+' ms');
    /* document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data; */
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = msg;
    var ajaxEnddd = new Date().getTime();
    /* console.log("Hello"); */
    
     document.getElementById("demorst").innerHTML ="Ajax Response Time: "+localStorage.getItem('rst')+" ms";
     document.getElementById("democbt").innerHTML ="Ajax Callback Time: "+(ajaxEnddd - localStorage.getItem('rs4date'))+" ms";
      }
  }) 
  /* var ajaxEnd = new Date().getTime();
  document.getElementById("demom").innerHTML = ajaxEnd - ajaxTime; */
  
 });
  
 });
</script>


And the js file is
 XHR.prototype.send = function(data) {
       
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      
     var self = this;
        var start;
        var oldOnReadyStateChange;
        var url = this._url;
        
        if (self.readyState == 1){
         
            var rs1date = new Date().getTime();
             localStorage.setItem('rs1date', rs1date);
          } 
        
        function onReadyStateChange() { 
    if(self.readyState == 4 && self.status == 200) {
             
             
             var rs4date = new Date().getTime();
            
             localStorage.setItem('rs4date', rs4date);
             var rst = (localStorage.getItem('rs4date')-localStorage.getItem('rs1date'));
             localStorage.setItem('rst',rst);
  
            }
//From html file when I'm doing ajax call it calling js file too, and I
```

//From html file when I'm doing ajax call it calling js file too, and I

Comment: do you want to know time duration of ajax call?

Comment: Snippets are to be run, please consider putting readable, working code inside them.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you want to know how much time take your request, you use something like this :

```js
const dateBegining = Date.now()

fetch("https://swapi.co/api/planets/3/")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(j => {
        const dateEnding = Date.now()
        console.log(`The API call took ${dateEnding - dateBegining} ms`)
        console.log(j)
    })
```